# Tap to disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm relativity new to Xcode and I was making a small just-for-fun kinda game for the iPhone and I'm having some trouble as far as making a certain sprite disappear when it spawns.

**Brief:** 
So basically I have a sprite spawning on screen each time every 0.70 seconds and that sprite is set to a global IBOutlet variable called "Circle". These circles spawn at random locations around the screen of the iPhone at random widths and heights.

**Overall**
So basically I'm trying to make it so that when you click on the exact circle, it only hides that ball.

Thanks. Also, sorry to the mods for the sloppy formatting.

Here's the code in file that's relevant:
**GameController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.gameState = GameStatePaused;
    circleVerlocity = CGPointMake(CircleSpeedX, CircleSpeedY);
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:SpawnSpeed target:self selector:@selector(addCircle:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:BallSpeed target:self selector:@selector(gameLoop) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)addCircle: (NSTimer *) aTimer {

    if(gameState == GameStateRunning)
    {
        UIImageView *Circle1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sprite-small-1.png"]];
        self.Circle = Circle1;
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(arc4random() % (274), arc4random() % (532), 50, 50);
        [Circle1 setFrame:rect];
        [self.view addSubview:Circle1];
    }
}

-(void)gameLoop
{
    if(gameState == GameStateRunning)
    {
        Circle.center = CGPointMake(Circle.center.x + circleVerlocity.x, Circle.center.y + circleVerlocity.y);

        if(Circle.center.x > self.view.bounds.size.width || Circle.center.x < 0)
        {
            circleVerlocity.x = -circleVerlocity.x;
        }

        if(Circle.center.y > self.view.bounds.size.height || Circle.center.y < 0)
        {
            circleVerlocity.y = -circleVerlocity.y;
        }

    }else{
        if(tapToBegin.hidden)
        {
            tapToBegin.hidden = NO;
        }
    }
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if(gameState == GameStatePaused)
    {
        tapToBegin.hidden = YES;
        gameState = GameStateRunning;
    }

    if([touch view] == Circle)
    {
        Circle.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `GestureRecognizer` in your circle. with class `UITapGestureRecognizer` you could add a recognizer to an element,

```
  circle.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideThatBall)];
  [circle addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];


-(void)hideThatBall{
   circle.hidden = YES;
}
```

I would use something like this

Comment: Ah ok thanks!! Where would you recommend I put the userintraction stuff in my code? :P

Comment: I usually add it when I create the object, the circle in your case. I also add the tapGesture after the object creation

Comment: Oh ignore that. Aha. Yeah I'm having some issues where the appear on screen and go but some stay on there and when I click them they don't disappear? It's weird.

Comment: Maybe you have to add `self.view.userInteractionEnables = YES;` too. It is weird.. it works for me

Comment: Make some debug tasks, add `NSLog` to the method and look what happens.